# Validação de objeto javascript / jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Perdi um pouco de tempo com uma validação em *javascript* e fiquei com a dúvida na cabeça: preciso saber se um elemento existe através do *id*.

Tentei de algumas formas e não obtive sucesso:

```
//tentativa 1
$('#idDiv').val() != undefined

//tentativa 2
typeof($('#idDiv').val()) != 'undefined'

//tentativa 3
var varIdDiv = $('#idDiv').attr("value");
if (varIdDiv) { /*código maroto*/ }
```

Por fim encontrei uma forma de validar que funcionou:

```
if ($('#idDiv').length > 0) { /*código maroto*/ }
```

Entendo que em linguagens como [C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info), a validação se parece mais com as formas que não deram certo (checando se o objeto existe/não nulo).

Minha dúvida é qual seria forma mais eficaz de validar se um objeto existe via *javascript*/*jquery*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que queres usar é a [propriedade `.length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/) que indica o numero de elementos no objecto jQuery.

```
if ($("#idDiv) { console.log("existe"); }
```

O jQuery retorna sempre um objeto. Seja um seletor, uma array, etc. Ele retorna sempre um objeto. Quando usa

```
if (typeof($("#idDiv")) !== "undefined") { console.log("existe");  }
```

está a verificar se `typeof {} !== "undefined"` o que dá sempre verdadeiro.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar apenas (sem `>0`):

```
if ($('#idDiv').length) { /*código maroto*/ }
```

Porque se o objeto existe, retornará `>0` ou `true`, caso contrário, `0` ou `false`.